# SQL Server query to get total against each month of a year and return the year and month in date format not the string format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a situation in which i have to calculate "Total" for each month of a year and i have to show total for each month of the year while maintaining datetime format of the date.i am writing the following query:

```
SELECT [DATE_FORMATION], sum(CO) CO, sum(Total_Members) Total_Members
from (
    select  convert(varchar(7),CAST([DATE_FORMATION] AS DATE),126) as [DATE_FORMATION],
    count([CO_ID]) as CO,
    sum(convert(int,[TOTAL_MEMBERS])) as Total_Members
    from COCores
    where cast([DATE_FORMATION] as date) >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -10, current_timestamp)), 0)
    group by [DATE_FORMATION]
) tmp
group by [DATE_FORMATION]
```

It is giving the accurate answer which i required

[image]

but the problem is it generates date in "Varchar" format where as i require it in datetime format so that i can use it further.how can i get this result while keeping the date in datetime format and getting the same result.

Comment: MySQL is a different product with different syntax. As for dates, they have **no format**, they are binary values. Formats apply only when parsing a string to a date, of formatting a date as a string. Don't store dates as strings. Use the correct type, `date`. When you want to generate a string, use `CONVERT` or `FORMAT` to generate the string you want

Comment: Same goes for numbers. You shouldn't have to cast `TOTAL_MEMBERS` to a number, it should be a number to begin with

Comment: have your tried to convert your date like 
Select Convert(DateTime,Date_Formation) as Date_Formation

Comment: @SyedWahhab the OP is already doing that. *That's* the bug to begin with

Comment: @Sadia what kind of output *do* you want? Your code *explicitly* truncates the day part. What do you want to display?

Comment: In this whole query i am having problem with the "Date_Formation" i have extracted the Year and MOnth out of it but in my .net program it is giving error becoz the date is in string format and not the date format.this is what i am trying to resolve, how can i get total against months of year adn still keep the format as date

Comment: @Sadia you haven't extracted the year and month, you formatted the date as a string and truncated the day. Dates have no format. What *do* you want in the output?

Comment: @Sadia if you can understand a word 'Jugaad' you can use it in your query :-) . you may concatenate '-01' in your current date_formation and then convert it into datetime format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates have no formats, they are binary values, just like `int` or `decimal` or `binary`. `DATE_FORMATION` should be a date type, eg `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2`. If the column uses the correct type, the query can be simplified to just :

```
select
    datefromparts(Year(DATE_FORMATION),MONTH(DATE_FORMATION),1) as DATE_FORMATION,  
    count([CO_ID]) as CO,
    sum([TOTAL_MEMBERS]) as Total_Members
from COCores
where 
    [DATE_FORMATION] as date) >= DATEFROMPARTS(Year(current_timestamp),1,1)
group by 
    YEAR(DATE_FORMATION),
    MONTH(DATE_FORMATION)
```

`DATEFROMPARTS(Year(current_timestamp),1,1)` returns the first date of the current year. This is used to return only rows in the current year. The results are grouped by the Year and Month of `DATE_FORMATION` using the YEAR and MONTH functions. Finally, SELECT returns the first day of each month by using `DATEFROMPARTS` to generate a date value from the group keys

Queries like this become *far* easier if you use [a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). A calendar table contains rows for each date eg for 50 years and extra columns for year, month, day, week number, names, etc that can be used to make reporting easier. Calendar tables are heavily indexed, allowing easy querying eg by year, quarter, semester etc.

Assuming `DATE_FORMATION` is a `date`, and a Calendar table with date, Year, Month and *StartOfMonth* columns, you could turn the query into :

```
select
    Calendar.StartOfMonth,  
    count([CO_ID]) as CO,
    sum([TOTAL_MEMBERS]) as Total_Members
from COCores inner join Calendar on DATE_FORMATION=Calendar.date
where 
    Calendar.Year= Year(current_timestamp)
group by 
    StartOfMonth
```

This query would be fast too as it can take advantage of any indexes on `Year`, `Date` and `StartOfMonth`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert all dates to first day of the month like so:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATE_FORMATION, -1))
```

It produces a `DATE`. You can use this expression in GROUP BY and in SELECT clause:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATE_FORMATION, -1)), COUNT(CO_ID) AS CO, SUM(CONVERT(INT, TOTAL_MEMBERS)) AS Total_Members
FROM COCores
WHERE DATE_FORMATION >= -- calculate -10 months
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATE_FORMATION, -1))
```